# How to replace CR and LF in Data Factory expressions

Tags: expression, azure-data-factory

There doesn't seem to be a clear answer to this, I am using a mapping data flow and a derived column expression.  I have data coming through that has spaces, carriage returns and line feeds, which I want to replace with nothing. For instance:

```
Jenny Mc Carthy  -  15 Somewhere Road
Someplace SomePostcode
SomeCity
```

This is columns: FirstName/LastName/Address. I want it to be:

```
JennyMcCarthy-15SomewhereRoadSomeplaceSomePostcodeSomeCity
```

Data Factory expressions should let me do this, I tried this and it didn't seem to work:

```
replace(replace(replace(FirstName+LastName+Address,' ',''),'\\r',''),'\\n','')
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I figured this out looking around at what others had done, I will put the answer here for other people to use.  It looks like you have to use the regexReplace function instead:

```
regexReplace(regexReplace(replace(firstname+lastname+address1,' ',''),`[\n]`,''),`[\r]`,'')
```

Note the weird quote marks in the regexReplace, yes your eyes aren't playing tricks on you, it's a [grave character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).

Answer (score 2):

For me, this works to replace the newline. Note the newline (I used shift-enter) between the single quotes as the 2nd value passed into the function.

@replace(FirstName+LastName+Address,'
', '')

This does NOT work: @replace(FirstName+LastName+Address,'\n', '')

Nor does this: @replace(FirstName+LastName+Address,'\\n', '')

By the way, my data factory doesn't have the function regexReplace, so that was not an option.

Comment: Yeah, note I was using a mapping data flow, where it is available (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions), while its not available in pipeline expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions