# DataFactory - Remove CR and LF characters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file source that has a field containing "CR" and "LF" type escape characters.

I'm trying to use a DataFlow and Derived Column to remove the unwanted characters but its not exactly working.

[Here is my input with the unwanted escape chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUFnC.png)

I'm using this expression against the synopsis column:

```
  regexReplace(regexReplace(synopsis, `[\n]`, ''),`[\r]`, '')
```

As suggested in this similar post - [How to replace CR and LF in Data Factory expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927629/how-to-replace-cr-and-lf-in-data-factory-expressions)

But I'm still getting some LF chars, but also a lot of extra commas.

[Here is my output still with LF and extra Commas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCKXZ.png)

Original in text format:
"TTL-100912","False",,"Bad Guys, The","GEN-ANI",,"Nobody has ever failed so hard at trying to be good as The Bad Guys.

In the new action comedy from DreamWorks Animation, based on the New York Times best-selling book series, a crackerjack criminal crew of animal outlaws are about to attempt their most challenging con yet--becoming model citizens.

Never have there been five friends as infamous as The Bad Guys--dashing pickpocket Mr. Wolf (Academy Award® winner Sam Rockwell, Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri), seen-it-all safecracker Mr. Snake (Marc Maron, GLOW), chill master-of-disguise Mr. Shark (Craig Robinson, Hot Tub Time Machine franchise), short-fused "muscle" Mr. Piranha (Anthony Ramos, In the Heights) and sharp-tongued expert hacker Ms. Tarantula (Awkwafina, Crazy Rich Asians), aka "Webs." The film co-stars Zazie Beetz (Joker), Lilly Singh (Bad Moms) and Emmy winner Alex Borstein (The Marvelous Mrs. Maisel).

Based on the blockbuster Scholastic book series by Aaron Blabey, THE BAD GUYS is directed by Pierre Perifel (animator, the Kung Fu Panda films), making his feature-directing debut. The film is produced by Damon Ross (development executive Trolls, The Boss Baby, co-producer Nacho Libre) and Rebecca Huntley (associate producer, The Boss Baby). The executive producers are Aaron Blabey, Etan Cohen and Patrick Hughes. ",,"BAD GUYS, THE","Bad Guys, The",,,,"2021-10-12 15:39:24",,

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide a sample of your CSV source in a text format instead of the screenshot to be able to repro it?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT I've edited my question to include the text, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way the source file was being produced was my complicating factor.

I changed the Row Delimiter in the production of my source csv to "¬" from "," and then was able to use this expression in a data flow to clean the contents of the Synopsis field:

```
regexReplace(synopsis, ',|[\n]|[\r]', ' ')
```